# Why <details> html tag is not used as hamburger menu?

Tags: html, hamburger-menu

I have never seen this but it looks like a perfect fit for `<details>`.

Is this bad for SEO or why it's not used?
`<details>` already works as a hamburger without javascript and its global support is 96.6% on https://caniuse.com/?search=details.

Have you thought about this option?

---

There are several ways to do this, you can have only `<details>`, or `<details>` and a standard `<nav>` and toggle `display: none;` based on media query. Should `<details>` have a `<nav>` inside it or outside?

Comment: Why hasn't `aside` been used? Why hasn't `p` been used (it probably has...)? Who knows? The title question is asking for guesses. There are at least four questions in this one question, so it's far too broad anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: TL:DR; Because it doesn't "make sense"**

1. Details is a semantic tag that should keep its meaning irrespective of layout. Hamburger is usually mobile-only, i.e. responsive / presentation territory.
2. Same reasoning goes for accessibility – if it's less than important, it should be that way all the time. Even if details become "open" on the desktop via styling, they'd still be "details" in a screen reader.
3. Browsers give it default styling that's arguably not so easily overridden.

Edit: And to the point – I'd say it does nothing whatsoever to your SEO, bad or good.

Comment: Are you saying that the current techniques used for hamburger menus are better semantically or for accessibility? Which ones?

Comment: for either, `menu > li` usually makes the most sense, possibly wrapped in a `nav`

Comment: Lucian Davidescu: I agree that menu should be the correct tag semantically. I have considered it in the past. Unfortunately, it is still experimental. Maybe in the future. And it has no opening or closing mechanism yet (as "details" or "select" tags have). In my opinion, a standard opening and closing mechanism is necessary, not just on "mobile" devices, because without it, developers only generate hideous codes, which differ from site to site, and as a result does not help including accessibility.

Comment: "it is still experimental" - it's not implemented in any way in browsers, but also it's not breaking anything and it's valid html – indeed just a fancy sort of `ul > li`, which of course... is always an option.

Comment: "standard opening and closing mechanism is necessary" well, the problem with browser-implemented functionality is that you need to first reset/override it. for once, they are not always implemented the same accross browsers and that's a headache. worse than that, implementations may change in the future and then your overrides could break. i think this could be a bigger issue than an inert `menu` element.

Comment: Lucian Davidescu: Regarding the opening and closing mechanism, it's not really "new". Since Lisa and the first Macintosh almost 40 years ago, a menu has a "menu bar", and expands when you click on one of its items. Note that the first expansion occurs when clicking, not just when hovering. Consistently, submenus can be expanded by clicking or hovering. The burger just has a menu bar reduced to one item. Nothing specific in his behavior. Nothing specific to mobile devices. Nothing specific depending on the application.

Comment: never said there was anything "new" (about `details` / `summary`, I suppose) just that it has a default behaviour that you need to override if you want to repurpose it as 'hamburger'. I understand your point and I think it's perfectly valid as long as the functionality is constant *throughout* views, so there's no change in semantics. However, the "hamburger" is currently used mainly just as a *contextual* space-saving convention, driven by the constraints of phones and tablets, so not really mark-up territory, rather just styling.

Comment: btw, with `details`, when the hamburger becomes full menu on desktop, it has to be set 'open' by default, which kind of voids the whole point of it when not done by the user.

Comment: that might be a good test: it's ok to use details only as long as they are not open by default irrespective of view, but only by user (or contextual script) action.

Comment: You don't have to use only ```details```, you can have a normal ```nav``` and details and toggle between them with media query. This way 1 is solved, 2 idk what you mean by saying "if it's less than important, it should be that way all the time" but details would be replaced with ```nav``` so I think that is fixed as well, 3 I found that closing or opening of details cannot be styled but I don't remember which one. This solution would require all navigation items duplicated ofcourse.

Comment: link2name: "details" can be inside a "nav" (this is of course what one needs to do if it is used for a menu), can be styled when it is open or closed as well,  and doesn't require to duplicate anything.

Comment: @link2name
`"you can have a normal nav and details and toggle between them with media query. This way 1 is solved"`
if I understand coreectly, you're suggesting a duplicate menu in html mark-up. actually, that would only make matters worse.
first, you're still conveying different semantics based on screen-width / orientation, just in another way, so not quite solved.

Comment: second, this is bad-practice, ugly, probably bad for accesibility and now there's some remote chance that it *may* affect your SEO (think cloaking, stuffing, duplication)... also google is probably used to just everything, because...
third, indeed many theme developers, especially with wordpress, went that way just because it made their workflows easier. it doesn't make it right, though – the point of responsive css is to reuse the same mark-up across mediums, not to duplicate it in the background.

Comment: `idk what you mean by saying "if it's less than important, it should be that way all the time"`
*if* the "hamburger" menu is used like most of the times these days, for saving space on mobile, than it's just a styling decision and the semantics should stay unchanged on wide screens.

Comment: if you add the "open" attribute by default to "details", than it's obviously not the case. for mobile users you're saying: 'here's some additional info about this subject, *if you're interested*, click to see more'. for desktop users, you're saying: 'here's some additional info about this subject, but since *you have such a big screen* we'll just show it to you anyway'.
Like I said earlier, this would not be as bead as duplicating the item, though.

Comment: *for clarity in the comment above: 'google is probably used to just everything' = google has seen this shit so often that it learned to turn a blind eye and let it be, so realistically the chance of something very bad happening is remote

Comment: @LucianDavidescu What exactly do you mean when you say semantics?

Comment: * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics#semantics_in_html
* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML
* https://nikitahl.com/why-it-is-important-to-write-semantic-html/

Comment: But isn't saying here is a menu, and here is a button to expand menu depending on user screen width exactly what you want to convey to the user? The nav in hamburger and normal nav aren't same type of things. You still need buttons to open or close hamburger and you still need to hide or show them, except they are just buttons, you would need an extra work to make it accessible, while details already works.

Comment: `depending on user screen width` is the key here. 
Not all user agents use screens (think screen-readers, bots etc.), so 'width' is something irrelevant to them.
Semantic html means that your markup is meaningful in itself and should not change on any medium - wide screen, narrow screen, no screen, whatever.
When that needs to be done, than it's purely a matter of styling, with classes and css.

Comment: Of course you could use 'open' as a hook for css (like any attribute), you can initiate it open and hide it with styling only when need it (weird choice if you ask me), you can switch it open automatically with JS (what's the point, it user or functional script action that was supposed to do that) - but all those only mean that you've repurposed/misused a semantic attribute as a class.

Comment: Especially with special purpose elements, you can always do the no-styling test. Load your website without css in a browser. Make the window narrow or wide – it will no longer respond, it's strictly semantic now. That's what any non-screen user-agent will "see". So, is this how you want it to "look" like? If it's satisfactory, sure, go ahead.

Comment: But it's only needed for specific width, if it isn't needed it won't be seen, why is this a problem then? You still change markup with buttons.

Comment: "if it isn't needed it won't be seen"...

see above: _do the no-styling test. Load your website without css in a browser_

That's how your website is *always* "seen" semantically, everything else is style

Comment: Why is this a meaningful test?

Comment: Because that's where your semantics are. Further reading: 
* http://web-accessibility.carnegiemuseums.org/foundations/semantic/
* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/HTML
* https://www.jungledisk.com/blog/2017/12/04/should-i-bother-with-semantic-html/
* https://bootcamp.uxdesign.cc/why-every-web-developer-should-know-about-semantic-html-83b61eba4501
* https://levelup.gitconnected.com/semantic-markup-probably-doesnt-mean-what-you-think-9e44d2439b18

Comment: But by this logic any hamburger menu is wrong, even most used ones since they still require stuff that has to be hidden or visible.

Comment: Not at all. Again, semantics are covered strictly by html while styling belongs to CSS. It's perfectly legitimate to hide or collapse some things on a mobile screen because there's only so much space, or some others on a printer version because they wouldn't make sense on paper and so on. But only if it's done with styling, without altering your underlying html, that should ideally make sense (hence "semantics") on its own, no matter how it ends up being displayed.

Comment: Now, I'm aware that these things are unimportant for most people and it's hard to argue with some points or use cases. "Why not mix markup with style? After all, display is all I really care about and it's easier like this. This whole semantics thing is pointless and extreme" (last 3 linked articles address that in length, may also want to read this too: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20134295 )...

Comment: ...but since the question is essentially about _proper_ use of a HTML element, the answer is about that as well. You can either do things "wrong" and own up to that or you can try and do them "right" – just don't expect your repurposing to be publically validated and accepted as standard / good practice – that will almost never happen. 
In brief –  
Q: "Why <details> html tag is not used as hamburger menu?" 
A: Because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: But would adding html buttons to open or close navigation be considered not semantic as well?

Comment: 1) You could always just use general purpose _divs_ or _spans_, that will not affect semantics at all. 2) There's also this semantic element for a `button` called just that, to execute whatever assigned functions. Since I get that the underlying question is "but what if a function is relevant to display?", the answer is that because you've used a proper, semantic element, there's a very good chance that user agents will know when to gracefully ignore it. 3) If you want to help them fare even better, you may want to look into aria roles.

Comment: 1) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div 
2) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button 
3) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles

Comment: With `details`, to more easily understand the semantics, think of it as a link – with the the `summary` being the anchor and the content being the target 'page'. Sometimes you may decide that it makes more sense or it's easier to just hold the content hidden in the current document until clicked, instead of opening a new document for each relevant anchor. Still, the content could just as well be worthy of having its own page, that a user can choose to read or not. So... Would you ever put your navigation menu on its own page? Would you open a link automatically because the screen got bigger?

Comment: But what is a semantic use for buttons if you see navigation anyway when all styling is disabled.

Comment: See above (2nd link / emphasis mine):
The <button> HTML element *represents a clickable button*, used to submit forms or anywhere in a document for accessible, *standard button functionality*.
By default, HTML buttons _are presented in a style resembling the platform the user agent runs on_, but you _can change_ buttons’ appearance with CSS.

Comment: A `button` element is semantic because 1) it can be clicked (which is a functional event, not a styling issue),  2) unlike `a`, it does an action not point to a resource, 3) unlike `details`, it says 'click me to do something', not 'click me if you want to find out more about this particular topic'. So not too general nor too specific, just the right tool for the right job, that is clicking for whatever functionality, irrespective of the user-agents' specific styling. Again, if the assigned function is exclusively display-related, you might always use `aria-hidden="true"`.

Comment: Isn't 'click me if you want to find out more about this particular topic' more semantically close to hamburger than 'click me to do something'? If it is such a huge problem with double navigation that is hidden or shown with css (in case when css is disabled) then lets just use js to add or delete details nav or a simple nav.

Comment: Are you trying to convince me or yourself? Kindly consolidate on where exactly semantics apply and _where they don't_. (hint: not all user agents use js)
Look, let's say there are three kinds of approaches: 
1. Most people don't care about the issue and one couldn't blame them too much. They just `div` everything and that's that. Fair enough, the web is slowly learning to cope with it. 
2. Then there are a few who do care and try to get it right, where 'right' means specs and consensus on best practices. Without those, a standard (be it good, or laking or bad!) is of no use whatsoever.

Comment: 3. Then there's this handful of revolutionaries who want to bend the standard to their own expectations. Which is not necessarily a bad thing, depending on how you do it. Either:
a) Do it in your own way, which is useless for you and potentially harmful for your readers (no semantics are better than wrong semantics!) and keep wondering why _everyone else_ "is doing it wrong". 
b) Do your homework, learn the concepts, get acccepted in the relevant workgroups and advocate for change and progress. After some good work, you may see some of your ideas put in practice for the benefit of mankind.

Comment: If js is disabled as well then user won't see hamburger and will just see normal menu, this is better than seing normal menu and some buttons to open and close it which don't work.

Comment: If by "normal menu" you mean a closed `details` element with just a visible `summary`, than yes – that's what they'll "see". Have kept pointing out that this is neither spec nor user expectation for a "menu", therefore is unsemantic. Since my answer pertains to the question "Why <details> html tag is not used as hamburger menu?", not to individual preferences and approaches – that may keep any discussion on forever - I'll stop here, just leaving the summary below for the record in case it became hard to follow for anyone...

Comment: *HTML*: _structure_, _semantics_; *CSS*: _style_, some _functionality_; *JS*: _functionality_, some _style_, some _structure_. So, **semantics belongs to html only** (certainly you can chose to alter the DOM with JS to actually change the HTML, but that's not the issue here and would just make things harder anyway – see graceful degradation, progressive enhancement, ARIA roles)

Comment: Normal menu means nav with links, no details at all, this way user gets better semantics than what you suggested because there are no useless buttons that do nothing.

Comment: "doing nothing" is fine and accepted, that's why divs still exists inter alia. see way above: _(...) there's a very good chance that user agents will know when to gracefully ignore it(...)_